# CMake find_library works but still get undefined references

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to use find_library and target_link_libraries to link a static library (libsndfile) in Windows. The find_library command works (which I can verify with a message) but I still get undefined references when I run make (using MinGW/mingw32-make).

Am I doing something wrong in my CMakeLists.txt file, or is there something else I'm missing?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

# Project name
project(ClickDetect)

include_directories(
    .
    D:/libs/libsndfile/include
)

# Tried adding this:
#link_directories (D:/libs/libsndfile/lib)

# Define the C sources
set ( OSLCODA_SRCS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ALT/find_click.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ALT/four1.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/osl_coda.c
)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( ${OSLCODA_SRCS} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C )

#Tried this way:
#SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(SNDFILE PROPERTIES
#    IMPORTED_LOCATION D:/libs/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.a)

# This seems to find the library... either .a or .lib
find_library(SNDFILE NAMES "libsndfile-1.a"
  PATHS "D:/libs/libsndfile/lib" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)


# Prints "SNDFILE: D:/libs/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.a"
if(NOT SNDFILE)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "libsndfile Not Found!")
else()
  message(STATUS "SNDFILE: ${SNDFILE}")
endif()

add_executable(oslcoda ${OSLCODA_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(oslcoda ${SNDFILE} )
```

output:

```
D:\FORCE\ClickDetect>cmake D:\FORCE\ClickDetect -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -BD:\FORCE\ClickDetect/cmake-build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt5.7/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt5.7/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt5.7/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt5.7/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- SNDFILE: D:/libs/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build

D:\FORCE\ClickDetect>cd cmake-build

D:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build>mingw32-make VERBOSE=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HD:\FORCE\ClickDetect -BD:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start D:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build\CMakeFiles D:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build'
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/oslcoda.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" D:\FORCE\ClickDetect D:\FORCE\ClickDetect D:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build D:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build D:\FORCE\ClickDetect\cmake-build\CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build'
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/oslcoda.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build'
[ 25%] Linking C executable oslcoda.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir/objects.a
C:\Qt5.7\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\Qt5.7\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\gcc.exe  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o oslcoda.exe -Wl,--out-implib,liboslcoda.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\linklibs.rsp
CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir/objects.a(osl_coda.c.obj):osl_coda.c:(.text.startup+0x1c9): undefined reference to `sf_open'
CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir/objects.a(osl_coda.c.obj):osl_coda.c:(.text.startup+0x2a4): undefined reference to `sf_read_int'
CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir/objects.a(osl_coda.c.obj):osl_coda.c:(.text.startup+0x3b7): undefined reference to `sf_read_int'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\build.make:151: recipe for target 'oslcoda.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [oslcoda.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/oslcoda.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/oslcoda.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/FORCE/ClickDetect/cmake-build'
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**EDIT**:

Contents of linklibs.rsp:

```
D:/libs/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

**UPDATE**

Tsyvarev is correct the error doesn't appear to be with cmake at all, I just don't understand how CMake selects its toolchain. As suggested in the comments I ran the link command manually and got the same error. It turns out the original build was done with MSYS/MinGW and I had both it and my Qt MinGW on my path. CMake was using my Qt install, which I thought was fine but it doesn't work (i guess because it's a 64 bit build of the lib).

So after a lot of wrestling with paths and CC and CXX variables I have it linking using MSYS mingw64. I'm still not sure if I understand how to properly switch the toolchain though. I tried just using CC and CXX to set the compiler location but things get very confused if you have mulitple toolchains on your system path. In the end I had to leave CC and CXX blank and just make sure the MSYS path is ahead of my Qt install on the path so CMake picks it up and nothing else. This will probably screw up builds for my other projects.

Comment: Run `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1` to see command lines. Check that library is present in the linker input.

Comment: I tried that but i'm not sure I got any information from it. I Edited to add the verbose output. Does it tell you anything? There is a file in the CMakeFiles directory called linklibs.rsp which contains the path "D:/libs/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.a" and a bunch of other -l... flags

Comment: I don't see `libsndfile-1.lib` in the linker command line, it may be in `CMakeFiles\oslcoda.dir\linklibs.rsp`, can you show its contents?

Comment: As you link with a library and still get "undefined reference", then your library doesn't define these symbols, or defines them in a way incompatible with compiler you use. BTW, you link with `.lib` file, but `linklibs.rsp` contains `.a` one. This looks ... rather strange.

Comment: I have switched between .a and .lib to test. The latest run used .a. in both cases the result is the same. Sorry for the mismatched output. The symbols definitely are definied. This is a widely used library and this code has been built for Windows before, just not using cmake. At first I thought it was using the C++ compiler and mangling the symbol names but explicitly using C language had no effect. Is there some other reason symbol names could be mismatched?

Comment: Please, update your post for make output consistent. As for "unresolved symbols" - you may try to execute given command line (with content of `linklibs.rsp` in it) and see what happens. If you got the same error, then the problem isn't in CMake.